# Resetting Python logging module defaults (Python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, logging

I seem to have somehow changed the default logging library behavior globally, and I'm not sure how to restore the defaults. According to the documentation, the default logging level is logging.WARNING (30), but when I run the following in my virtualenv:

```
import logging
print logging.getLogger.getEffectiveLevel()
```

The output is 40 (logging.CRITICAL). Next example (REPL):

```
import logging
logging.getLogger().getEffectiveLevel()
>>> 40
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger().getEffectiveLevel()
>>> 40
```

Why does basicConfig have no effect? Lastly, if I run the following in the REPL:

```
import logging
logging.shutdown()
reload(logging)
logging.getLogger().getEffectiveLevel()
>>> 30
```

The output is 30 (logging.WARNING), which is the correct default. Is it possible I have a configuration file or something preventing the defaults from working correctly?

I am running on Mac OSX with a Python 2.7.10 virtualenv.

Comment: Is this `import logging; logging.getLogger().getEffectiveLevel()` showing 40 seen in a freshly opened Python interpreter session?

Comment: @wim yes. All three examples are started from a fresh REPL.

Comment: do you have any log configuration files lying around? what were you doing to mess it up in the first place?

Comment: It's possible, but I've inherited the source code and the virtualenv, so I'm not sure where to look for the configuration file, or what it would be called. I'm not the one who changed it, so I'm not sure what was done to set the defaults this way.

Comment: If you create and activate a new virtualenv (don't remove the existing one), do you see the same?